# group by columns values combination

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
+---+---+---
|  A|  B| 
+---+---+
|  1|  3|
|  1|  1|
|  1|  2|
|  1|  5| 
|  2|  5| 
|  2|  2| 
|  2|  1| 
|  3|  1| 
|  3|  2|
|  3|  5|
|  4|  3| 
|  4|  4|
|  5|  4|
|  5|  3|
|  6|  2|
|  6|  5|
|  6|  1|
|  6|  3|
|  7|  5|
|  7|  4|
|  7|  3|

+---+---+
```

i want to have the count of the occurrence of two values of B together for each A to get the most common combination of two values of  B, (the order doesn't matter)
i want the result to be :`[1,2],[1,5],[1,2] and [3,4]` as the values of B appearing the most together( i mean for the same A )
I have tried this :

```
oc=pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B_combination'])
oc['B_combination']=df.astype('str').groupby('A')['B'].agg([ ';'.join,lambda x: set(x.tolist())])['<lambda_0>'].values
oc['A']=df.astype('str').groupby('A')['B'].agg([ ';'.join,lambda x: set(x.tolist())])['<lambda_0>'].index
```

to get the different combination like this  :

```
|A |B_combination|
---+--------------
|1 |{2, 1, 3, 5} |
|2 |{2, 1, 5}    |
|3 |{2, 1, 5}    |
|4 |{4, 3}       |
|5 |{4, 3}       |
|6 |{2, 1, 3, 5} |
|7 |{4, 3, 5}    |
```

but when i apply

```
oc.groupby('B_combination').count()
```

to get the most commun combination it doesnt work because it is a set i tried to convert to alist but same it didn't work

Comment: can you add your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `itertools.combinations` with `groupby()`:

```
(df.groupby('A')['B']
   .apply(lambda x: pd.Series([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in combinations(x,2)]).value_counts())
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
    A level_1  B
0   1  (3, 5)  1
1   1  (2, 5)  1
2   1  (3, 1)  1
3   1  (3, 2)  1
4   1  (1, 5)  1
5   1  (1, 2)  1
6   2  (2, 1)  1
7   2  (5, 1)  1
8   2  (5, 2)  1
9   3  (2, 5)  1
10  3  (1, 5)  1
11  3  (1, 2)  1
12  4  (3, 4)  1
13  5  (4, 3)  1
14  6  (5, 3)  1
15  6  (2, 1)  1
16  6  (2, 3)  1
17  6  (1, 3)  1
18  6  (2, 5)  1
19  6  (5, 1)  1
20  7  (5, 3)  1
21  7  (5, 4)  1
22  7  (4, 3)  1
```

Comment: if you use Counter from collections and `map` I think you can make this much simplier `from collections import Counter`;`df['B'].map(df['B'].agg(Counter)`

Comment: @Manakin While Counter might work, it’s can’t really bypass groupby here. You won’t get much simpler code base. That said, I’m happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: thank you that is helping me a lot but the problem is here that it is repeating like for (1,2) and (2,1) it is considering it is not the same while i want it to be the same

Comment: @user3379546 see updated answer. We only need to sort the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(set).reset_index(name='B_combination')
```